# Header Icons in wrong spot

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get 3 icons horizontally aligned with the title of my website.  I can't seem to get them within the same margin as my banner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
    CrossFit Villains
    </title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<body>
    <header>
        <span class="title">
            <a href="crossfitvillains.com">CrossFit Villains</a>
        </span>
        <div id="social">
            <img src="fb.png" />
            <img src="bird.png" />
            <img src="tv.png" />
        </div>

        <br />
        <span>1702 McAra Street, Regina, SK</span>
        <br />
        <br />
    </header>

    <div id="banner">
        <img src ="banner.jpg" />
    </div>
```

The CSS for the icons:

```
#social img {
    float: right;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle before so forgive me if I messed something up.  I didn't add all of the images. http://jsfiddle.net/zPZ2y/

Comment: Maybe a live link would be better. The fiddle as it is doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright,

First of all be sure to float the `a` elements instead of the `img`. 
The title should be floated as well, to lign them up correctly.

Also give classes to the other `span` element in your header so you can apply styles to it. Using `<br />` for a new line between **elements** in HTML is wrong practice.

```
span.title {
     float:left;   
}

#social {
    float:right;
}

#social a {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px; /* just for the spacing of the elements in example */
}
span.address { /* Added this class to the span in the HTML for styling */
    float:left;
}

div#banner {
  clear:both; /* to replace the <br /> tag */
}
```

Please see the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPZ2y/3/).

Note: The images weren't linked properly, so I gave the "icons" a red background and your body a black one for readability..

Cheers, Jeroen